# sveltejs - static properties on components

Tags: javascript, static-methods, svelte-3

I have a scenario where I need to provide information to a component class such that downstream instantiations can make use of that info.

For instance:

```
import { AComponent } from 'AComponent.svelte'
...
AComponent.classInfo = {something: somedata}
```

And then, the component could access that information as in:

```
<script>
  let something = AComponent.classInfo.something
</script>
```

There seemed to be some effort in providing this kind of functionality in V2 (I'm using 3) that was discussed in these issues: [Support Component Static Method #480](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/480), which resulted in [Added setup function which can supply static methods/properties. #572](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/752).

However, scanning the current docs reveals no such setup method.  So, did this survive from V2 to 3 & if not, is there some way to do this?

Comment: why not create a .js file, write your logic to generate the data for the component, then import this variable from the js file, in the component, this way the same data will be shared amongst all the components

Comment: Yeah, I could do something like that, and I might.  This is in an external component library, but it would still be possible by adding a .js function that exports a 'setSomething()' function and then the components in the lib could get access to the 'something' via a 'getSomething()' call.

Comment: Right now, I'm working around it using a sessionStorage object.  Store the 'something' in the sessionStorage and the components can get to it.

Comment: Neither of these approaches are optimal - I'd rather have the information completely encapsulated in the component definition.

Answer (score 7):

You can define *static* properties that are not instance specific in the module script block

```html
<script context="module">
  export const someValue = 123
</script>
<script>
  // Normal component stuff
</script>
```

and then import it directly from the component file:

```js
import { someValue } from './MyComponent.svelte'
```

Note that this is a value shared among all instances of this component.

Comment: In my case the lack of semi-colon from the example above broke the linting, so I needed to add it to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

At least in version v3.32, it's not possible to define static properties in a Svelte Component. Only named exports are possible.

The only workaround I known is using a custom webpack loader/rollup plugin, and the implementation is never pretty.